# Behavior of frequency in a sinusoidal circuit

Tags: frequency, cutoff-frequency

My question is in regards to a circuit like this with a sinusoidal voltage source Vin. When I try to figure out the voltage ratio between Vin and Vout I get ωCR/(ωCR - j). I then try to figure out what the Vout becomes when ω >> cutoff-frequency(1/RC) AND ω << frequency(1/RC). For the first instance, I get that Vout will be 1 because as the frequency becomes bigger, the capacitor acts like a short circuit. But what happens when the frequency becomes smaller than the cutoff frequency?

[image]

Comment: How this circuit behaves is standard network theory, tutorials can be found in many places. For example have you read: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/filter/filter_3.html ? And more details in: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/filcap.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite your equation as:

$$\frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}} = \frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{j\omega RC}}$$

Since R and C are constants, the question is what happens qualitatively as the value of ω changes.

- When ω = 1/RC, the \$\frac{1}{j\omega RC}\$ term is essentially unity (ignoring phase for the moment), so the overall expression becomes \$\frac{1}{1+j} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\$. This is known as the half-power, or -3 dB point, and we call this the cutoff frequency of the filter.
- When ω >> 1/RC, the \$\frac{1}{j\omega RC}\$ term becomes very small, so the overall expression becomes \$\frac{1}{1+0} = 1\$. As you say, the capacitor behaves as a short circuit.
- When ω << 1/RC, the \$\frac{1}{j\omega RC}\$ term becomes very large, so the overall expression becomes \$\frac{1}{\text{large number}} = 0\$. Now the capacitor behaves more and more as an open circuit.

Comment: In your first bullet point the overall expression is \$\frac{1}{1-j}\$ and the gain is \$\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \$, or in dB: \$\small 20\: log\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}=-3 \:dB\$

Comment: @Chu: Yes, that is correct. I said I was ignoring phase, trying to focus on the qualitative (rather than quantitative) aspects of the question.

Comment: But the gain is not \$\frac{1}{1+1}\$ and the half power point statement is a bit misleading.

Comment: @Chu: OK, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Although its a very basic question, you showed some thinking effort and thus deserve an answer.

This is a simple high pass filter. For a signal with frequency much bigger than the cutoff frequency, Vout = Vin. For very low frequency signals, Vout = 0 (independent of the input voltage).